# java how to send get request with header?

Tags: java, c#, http-headers

Hello guys I am trying to send get request in java with header. I am looking for a method like conn.addHeader("key","value); but I cannot find it. I tried "setRequestProperty" method but it doest not work..

```
public void sendGetRequest(String token) throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
    // Make a URL to the web page
    URL url = new URL("http://api.somewebsite.com/api/channels/playback/HLS");

    // Get the input stream through URL Connection
    URLConnection con = url.openConnection();

    //add request header
    con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
    con.setRequestProperty("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
    con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "bearer " + token);

    InputStream is = con.getInputStream();

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

    String line = null;

    // read each line and write to System.out
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
}
```

It returns Httpresponse 401 error.

My office mate use unity c# to send get request header his codes looks like the fallowing.

```
  JsonData jsonvale = JsonMapper.ToObject(reqDataGet);
        // Debug.Log(jsonvale["access_token"].ToString());
        // /*
        string url = "http://api.somewebsite.com/api/channels/playback/HLS";
        var request = new HTTPRequest(new Uri(url), HTTPMethods.Get, (req, resp) =>
        {
            switch (req.State)
            {
                case HTTPRequestStates.Finished:
                    if (resp.IsSuccess)
                    {
                    }
                    break;
            }

        });
        request.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
        request.AddHeader("Authorization", "bearer " + jsonvale["access_token"].ToString());
        request.Send();
```

Any help?

Answer (score 2):

In Java I think you want something like this.

```
    String url = "http://www.google.com/search?q=stackoverflow";

    URL obj = new URL(url);
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

    // optional default is GET
    con.setRequestMethod("GET");

    //add request header
    con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "My Example" );

    int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
```